# What is the best and easiest way to secure cookies

Tags: java, security, cookies

I am searching for a way that help me to secure cookies by encrypting them for example. I searched a lot and I got confused. Thus, I am seeking your help to find an easy way to do that.

Actually my aim is only to show that I can secure my cookies in Java for sensitive data such as password.

Comment: Why would you store data in the cookie?

Comment: For keeping the user name logged in for subsequent process.

Answer (score 2):

In a protected connection (SSL), everything is encrypted, cookies too. Yes you can implement an algorithm to encrypt cookies value, why not... but you have to encrypt/decrypt handly with your own code.

If you don't have a Java development tool, or the last paragraph scared you away from using one that you own, you can use the Java 2 Software Development Kit, which is available for free from Sun's Java Web site .

In addition to delivering the cookies over HTTPS (SSL), and encrypting the contents such that they cannot be manipulated via Man in the Middle attacks, there is an additional requirement. The cookie must also be marked as 'secure' per RFC2109 as in...

//snip

Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID:893ihewwydkq2764@&@09;Path=/;secure
//snip

Marking the cookies this way ensures they cannot be delivered over an unencrypted session such as http.

Using these three methods together makes a cookie reasonably 'SECURE'

Happy coding  :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate that, but as I don't have experience in this field and I have to do it, could you please point me to a helpful tutorial or sources that can benefit me?

Comment: Are you developing ASP.NET application ?

Comment: In that case you can see this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8742/Encrypting-Cookies-to-prevent-tampering

Comment: No, I am not using ASP.NET. I am willing to use simple coding as much as I can. Could you please tell me what is the simplest way to implement https?